# Перемещения сайта вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Что делать если сайта на глобалбном хосте не отображает стили и картинки. Предполагаю, что это из-за get_template_uri(он отображает старый хост). Но, когда пытаюсь вручную url тоже ничего не работает. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Приведите пример не правильных ссылок - проблема может быть в чем угодно, нет смысла гадать. Могу только предположить, что в таблице `wp_options` в строке `siteurl` забито старое доменное имя.

Comment: Вангую -  сайт был не правильно мигрирован на хостинг. См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress/767562#767562